# Python: if element in one list, change element in other?

Tags: python, list, comparison

I have two lists (of different lengths). One changes throughout the program (`list1`), the other (longer) doesn't (`list2`). Basically I have a function that is supposed to compare the elements in both lists, and if an element in `list1` is in `list2`, that element in a copy of `list2` is changed to 'A', and all other elements in the copy are changed to 'B'. I can get it to work when there is only one element in `list1`. But for some reason if the list is longer, all the elements in `list2` turn to B....

```
def newList(list1,list2):         
    newList= list2[:]  
    for i in range(len(list2)):  
        for element in list1:  
            if element==newList[i]:  
                newList[i]='A'  
            else:
                newList[i]='B'  
    return newList
```

Comment: Should that be `newList = list2[:]`?  (rather than `newList: list2[:]`?)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
newlist = ['A' if x in list1 else 'B' for x in list2]
```

Works for the following example, I hope I understood you correctly? If a value in `B` exists in `A`, insert `'A'` otherwise insert `'B'` into a new list?

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> b = [1,3,4,6]
>>> ['A' if x in a else 'B' for x in b]
['A', 'A', 'A', 'B']
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be because instead of

```
newList: list2[:]
```

you should have

```
newList = list2[:]
```

Personally, I prefer the following syntax, which I find to be more explicit:

```
import copy
newList = copy.copy(list2) # or copy.deepcopy
```

Now, I'd imagine part of the problem here is also that you use the same name, `newList`, for both your function and a local variable.  That's not so good.

```
def newList(changing_list, static_list):
    temporary_list = static_list[:]
    for index, content in enumerate(temporary_list):
        if content in changing_list:
            temporary_list[index] = 'A'
        else:
            temporary_list[index] = 'B'
    return temporary_list
```

Note here that you have not made it clear what to do when there are multiple entries in `list1` and `list2` that match.  My code marks all of the matching ones `'A'`.  Example:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = [3,4,7,2,6,8,9,1]
>>> newList(a,b)
['A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'A']
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want to do and can put newLis = list2[:] instead of the below but prefer to use list in these cases:

```
def newList1(list1,list2):         
     newLis = list(list2)
     for i in range(len(list2)):  
          if newLis[i] in list1:  
               newLis[i]='A'  
          else: newLis[i]='B'  
     return newLis
```

The answer when passed

```
newList1(range(5),range(10))
```

is:

```
['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B']
```